# Threejs: uploading scene from .obj and object manipulation

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I have a scene.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8913924/test2/index.html

Most of objects are loaded from a single .obj file.
Plus 2 handmade cubes.

Click on objects - it should change it's color.

Cubes are ok. 
Objects from obj file change its color all at once (but they shouldn't and it is my current Question).
(All clicks on objects are detected correctly. Inspect debug concole.)

Need your help and advices.

Add 2 handmade red cubes:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,10);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            mesh.position.z = 125;
            mesh.name = 'cube1';

            scene.add(mesh);

            geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,10);
            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            mesh.position.z = 175;
            mesh.name = 'cube2';

            scene.add(mesh);
```

Load objectcts from .obj:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    var object = event.content;

    // cubes are already here   
    scene.add(object);
}); loader.load( 'qwerty.obj', 'qwerty.mtl' );
```

Change color of the proper object:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.__objects );
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    // got the correct object with proper id
intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
}
```

Comment: you'd have to define different colors for the vertices/polys of your geometry

Comment: i am a newbie and i miss the point. Geometry of what mesh ? (i don't really understand why the different behaviour between cubes and other objects -- as for me they all are unrelated meshes. Examples, articles or something else would be fine.

Comment: "Most objects are loaded from a single obj file" that is mesh information. A mesh is just collected polygons. Each "object" you're talking about is its own collection of polygons. If you want more specific answers, you're going to have to post code and talk specifically about what you're trying to achieve and what is not working for you. I'm not gooogle. you want tutorials, google it. I will help you with specifics if you can provide specific problems.

Comment: from what I can tell you've assigned the same material to the whole geometry, not just "objects" with IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding your whole .obj scene as one object (`scene.add(object)`). So then, when you intersect your scene objects, `intersects[0].object` is your whole .obj, since that's what you've added to the scene.

I'm not familiar with the OBJMTLLoader,  but it looks like `event.content` in your first callback has a `children` property. Try doing this instead:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
var object = event.content;

// cubes are already here
for(var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++)   
    scene.add(object.children[i]);
}); loader.load( 'qwerty.obj', 'qwerty.mtl' );
```

EDIT:

Played with it and got it to work by cloning the materials. Basically, when the meshes are loaded they all share the same material definition (which is good as it saves resources). However, if you want to change the material properties independently, you need to replace this:

```
intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
```

by this:

```
if(!intersects[0].object.ownMaterial) intersects[0].object.material = intersects[0].object.material.clone();
intersects[0].object.ownMaterial = true;
intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
```

Comment: that's the way loader works for me. it seems like one object but in fact there all the objects with proper name and ids. for real i have 10+ objects. not 3 of them. (check the demo https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8913924/test2/index.html

Comment: I saw that, yes. Apparently they all share the same material object though (scene.__objects[7].material == scene.__objects[8].material), so you may want to create a new material after getting the intersected object.

Comment: thank you! it worked. The trick was in shared material. You are helpful.